# How to use WordPress' Lost_Password functions outside of the website?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I basically need to make an API for WordPress that allows simple user edits and such.
I've created an API for registering, creating users, retrieving categories, etc...

How can I use WordPress' internal scripts so I can pass it an email address or username and it will automatically email the user?

Comment: The functions are all in the openly-available WordPress source code.

Comment: That really doesn't help. I know they are, but where?

Comment: C'mon, it's not that hard. I just downloaded WP and searched for 'password' in the code. The function `retrieve_password` in `wp-login.php` appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I assume your script is running on the website root folder
include_once("wp-load.php");

// you script start here..
```